# Getting past Python value error for an integer

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to run the [SerendipSlim](https://github.com/uwgraphics/SerendipSlim) topic model visualisation tool. I have used the enclosed script for generating a topic model with MALLET ([VEP_TMScripts](https://github.com/uwgraphics/VEP_TMScripts)). When reading the created model with SerendipSlim, this line throws the following error:

```
topicNum = int(row[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0032876898047722344'
```

Any ideas on how to get past it?

Comment: That looks like a `float()`, if you want the floor `int` you can `int(float(row[i]))`.

Comment: it depends on what you want. Is there a valid case for trying to parse that as an int? what result do you want? do you simply want to ignore it, have a close value, have the exact value (not an int, obviously)

Comment: The code `topicNum`, I realise now, probably looks for a MALLET topic number (which is int format). Maybe the [i] reads from the wrong place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to "pass" it as mentioned you can use the float() for decimal number.

`topicNum = float(row[i])`.

for int representation you should use:

```
import math
new_topic_num = math.ceil(topicNum)

print new_topic_num
>> 1.0
```

now you can re-use the `int` for your later on `for i in range(int(new_topic_num))`

Comment: Tried that, but the decimals are then lost of course.

Comment: Hmm, then it throws `line 84, in get_theta
    topicMetadataList = [{} for i in range(maxTopic+1)]
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`instead.

Comment: I got it, then save another var the represents the complete number. use `round() ` method or `math.ceil() ` I will update my answer